# unlock android phone without smart lock

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, unlock

I would like to unlock an android phone each time it is in close proximity to a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device without using smartlock.
Is it possible to set up an unlock mechanism that speaks directly to the OS?

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing. We can use a beacon that we can carry in our pockets and whenever the phone is unlocked (swiping screen) it checks the presence of the trusted beacon